# How to Remove "Starting at" Price in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento

I need the code for how to remove the "Starting at" and "As Low As" price in Magento's latest version. We are using grouped products only and the "Grouped Products Pro" extension to list associated products in a table format.

The problem with the new "rwd" template is that it does not have a price.phtml file in the bundle directory. I've looked on several other forums to no avail.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Class **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product**

Method

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
{
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
    $this->setProduct($product);
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

sets catalog/product/price.phtml as template.

There you can find your labels:

```
        <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Starting at:') ?></span>
```

and

```
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
```

Comment: Where is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product located in the directory to place that code?